# Floating feedback form in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am displaying a floating feedback form in my website and using JQuery to handle the slide in and out functionality. Following is the code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SlidingWindow.Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajax" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>    

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat = "server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="feedback-panel">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat = "server">
<ContentTemplate>
<a class="feedback-tab" href="#"></a> 
<asp:Panel ID = "panel1" runat = "server">           
<table>
<tr style="height:100%;white-space:nowrap;"><td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat = "server" Text = "Name"></asp:Label></td></tr>
<tr style="height:100%;white-space:nowrap;"><td><asp:TextBox runat = "server" ID = "txtName" CssClass = "feedbacktextbox"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
<tr style="height:100%;white-space:nowrap;"><td><asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat = "server" Text = "Email"></asp:Label></td></tr>
<tr style="height:100%;white-space:nowrap;"><td><asp:TextBox runat = "server" ID = "txtEmail" CssClass = "feedbacktextbox"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
<tr style="height:100%;white-space:nowrap;"><td><asp:Label ID="lblFeedback" runat = "server" Text = "Comments"></asp:Label></td></tr>
<tr style="height:100%;white-space:nowrap;"><td><asp:TextBox runat = "server" ID = "txtFeedback" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass = "width"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
<tr style="height:100%;white-space:nowrap;"><td><asp:Button runat = "server" 
        ID = "btnFeedbackSubmit" Text = "Submit" onclick="btnFeedbackSubmit_Click"  />
</td></tr>
</table>   

</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID = "panel2" runat = "server"><asp:Label runat = "server" ID = "lblFeedbackMsg"></asp:Label></asp:Panel>           
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>   
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var feedbackTab = {
            speed: 300,
            containerWidth: $('.feedback-panel').outerWidth(),
            containerHeight: $('.feedback-panel').outerHeight(),
            tabWidth: $('.feedback-tab').outerWidth(),


            init: function () {
                $('.feedback-panel').css('height', feedbackTab.containerHeight + 'px');

                $('a.feedback-tab').click(function (event) {
                    if ($('.feedback-panel').hasClass('open')) {
                        $('.feedback-panel')
                .animate({ left: '-' + feedbackTab.containerWidth }, feedbackTab.speed)
                .removeClass('open');
                    } else {
                        $('.feedback-panel')
                .animate({ left: '0' }, feedbackTab.speed)
                .addClass('open');
                    }
                    //event.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        };

        feedbackTab.init();
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
          .feedback-panel {
    padding:5px;
    width: 250px;
    background:#C4C4FF;
    border: 5 solid #8080FF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: White;
    position:fixed;
    top:77px;
    left:-261px;
}

.feedback-panel a.feedback-tab {
    background: url(/images/feedbackbutton.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    display:block;
    height:122px;
    left:45px;
    bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:40px;
    outline:none;
}

.feedbackformtable
{
    width: 215px;
}

.feedbacklabel
{
    font-family: Arial Helvetica Sans-Serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: Black;
}

.feedbacktextbox
{
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #8080FF;
}

    </style>
```

The form is used to send feedback as an email. As soon as the submit button is clicked, the form is closed. Is there any way to keep the form open after clicking the submit button? I want to display a message on the form instead of closing it. Much appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add jquery file name which you are using for displaying floating form.

Comment: It is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js

Comment: Any other jquery file you are using. Because only this file is not working for me.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya That's the only file I'm using.